# Typed Form with shared and dynamic fields

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular17

I have an Angular 17 app with multiple views, each having its own search bar.
There are, however, two parameters ("name" and "age" for simplicity) that are used in most - but not all - search bars. All search bars also have additional parameters besides "name" and "age".

Following the DRY principle, I've created a `SharedSearchBarComponent` that contains FormControls for these two shared parameters as well as two buttons for submitting and resetting the form. It takes a FormGroup as an `@Input` and `<ng-content></ng-content>` serves as a slot for additional FormControls.
It works just fine, but I'm having difficulties typing the FormGroup input properly.
I provided a simplified version of the problem in this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rnztbg?file=src%2Fmain.ts).

Basically I want the `SharedSearchBarComponent` to accept a FormGroup that **definitely** has FormControls for "name" and "age" and some other FormControls that the `SharedSearchBarComponent` does not need to know anything about. These are just rendered inside `<ng-content></ng-content>`

I thought of something along the lines of

```js
@Input()
form: FormGroup<{name: FormControl<string>; age: FormControl<number>; [key: string]: AbstractControl}>
```

but that does not work. I tried `FormControl<any>` instead of `AbstractControl` and I cannot remember how many similar things. Every time the compiler says that the parentForm is not assignable to the FormGroup defined in `SharedSearchBarComponent`.

I know that there are other ways to solve this (e.g. use a nested form in the parent component and just pass the shared controls in a FormGroup down to the `SharedSearchBarComponent`, but I'm just curious as to how to tell the Typescript compiler what I want to achieve.

Comment: While this won't exactly fix your issue, [FormRecord](https://angular.dev/guide/forms/typed-forms#formrecord) is designed for dynamic forms.

Comment: @BojanKogoj Thanks for the hint. I tried it and while it handled the dynamic part well, I failed to get the fixed controls into the type.